# Syncfusion ButtonAdv

Tags: c#, wpf, syncfusion

so I'm trying to build an application where I'm using some of the ButtonAdv-controls.
As I'm also coding some triggers connected to it, I've to access the style.
However, I can't get the basedon attribute working on this one.

```
<Style x:Key="SyncButtonAdvMainPage" TargetType="{x:Type syncfusion:ButtonAdv}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroButtonAdvStyle}">
     <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"/>
     <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
     <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
     <Setter Property="SizeMode" Value="Normal"/>
     <Setter Property="IconHeight" Value="30"/>
</Style>
```

Gives me an error when using it for a control that the ressource couldn't be resolved.
It works for regular (not Syncfusion) buttons tough as I'm referencing the style and the theme in App.xaml.

```
<ResourceDictionary>
       <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
          <ResourceDictionary Source="/Syncfusion.Shared.WPF;component/SkinManager/MetroStyle.xaml"/>
       </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
       <Style x:Key="MetroButtonBase" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroButtonStyle}">
          <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
       </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Some ideas on this?
Thanks and greetings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have checked your code. In this you have merged MS control theme resource to Syncfusion ButtonAdv control. To override Syncfusion ButtonAdv control, you can use the below path.

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="/Syncfusion.Shared.WPF;component/Controls/ButtonControls/Button/Themes/MetroStyle.xaml" />
```

You can get the resource path for Syncfusion controls in below link.

https://help.syncfusion.com/wpf/skinmanager/overview#resourcedictionary-path-for-syncfusion-themes

I have override ButtonAdv control style with BasedOn property to use Metro ButtonAdv Style and created simple sample. Please find it below.

Sample: http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/ButtonAdvSample-422062150180166807

Regards,

Keerthana J.